# Query to return records within the same business year

Tags: sql, ms-access

Why are records which were entered before `31/07/2021` still showing in this query? I want to show records in the current business year only.

Company business year Starts in `01/08/YYYY` and end on `31/07/YYYY` the next year. Can the query works for every business year? i.e. "at this point of time next year".

I have this SQL code so far:

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(DATEADD("m", 5, [OrderDate]), "\Qq") AS Quarter, *
FROM 
    tblOrders
WHERE 
    [OrderDate] BETWEEN DateSerial(Year(Date()) - 1, 8, 1) 
                    AND DateSerial(Year(Date()), 8, 0)
ORDER BY 
    tblOrders.OrderDate DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

DateSerial(Year(Date()) - 1, 8, 1) returns 01.08.2020 and DateSerial(Year(Date()), 8, 0) returns 31.07.2021. So in the end you are getting all the dates between 01.08.2020 and 31.07.2021.

I guess you could make the Year(Date()) dynamic. In case current date is equal or past 01.08.XXXX but not past 31.12.XXXX then it should be current year and current year + 1 otherwise it should stay as it is now - current year - 1 and current year.

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(DATEADD("m", 5, [OrderDate]), "\Qq") AS Quarter, *
FROM 
    tblOrders
WHERE 
    [OrderDate] BETWEEN IIF(Date() >= DateSerial(Year(Date()), 8, 1)  AND Date() <= DateSerial(Year(Date()), 13, 0), DateSerial(Year(Date()), 8, 1), DateSerial(Year(Date()) - 1, 8, 1))
                AND IIF(Date() >= DateSerial(Year(Date()), 8, 1) AND Date() <= DateSerial(Year(Date()), 13, 0), DateSerial(Year(Date()) + 1, 8, 0), DateSerial(Year(Date()), 8, 0))
ORDER BY 
    tblOrders.OrderDate DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use these two functions found in module *DateBank* here: [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date).

```vb
' Returns the primo calendar date of the specified financial/fiscal year.
' Returns the primo calender date of the current financial year, if no
' financial year is specified.
'
' 2021-05-09. Gustav Brock. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DateFinancialYearPrimo( _
    Optional ByVal FinancialYear As Integer) _
    As Date
    
    Dim Month       As Integer
    Dim Day         As Integer
    Dim Years       As Integer
    Dim Primo       As Date
    
    Month = VBA.Month(DateFinancialStart())
    Day = VBA.Day(DateFinancialStart())
    
    If IsYear(FinancialYear) Then
        Years = FinancialYear - VBA.Year(FinancialStart)
        If Month = MinMonthValue And Day = MinDayValue Then
            ' The financial year is the calendar year.
        Else
            Years = Years - 1
        End If
    Else
        Years = VBA.Year(DateCalendar(Date)) - VBA.Year(FinancialStart)
    End If
    
    Primo = DateAdd("yyyy", Years, FinancialStart)

    DateFinancialYearPrimo = Primo
    
End Function


' Returns the ultimo calendar date of the specified financial/fiscal year.
' Returns the ultimo calender date of the current financial year, if no
' financial year is specified.
'
' 2021-05-09. Gustav Brock. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DateFinancialYearUltimo( _
    Optional ByVal FinancialYear As Integer) _
    As Date
    
    Dim Ultimo      As Date
        
    Ultimo = DateAdd("d", -1, DateAdd("yyyy", 1, DateFinancialYearPrimo(FinancialYear)))
    
    DateFinancialYearUltimo = Ultimo

End Function


' Gets or sets the start day and month of the financial/fiscal year as a
' date value applied a neutral year.
'
' The start month can be any month.
' The start day can be any day less than or equal 28, which is the
' highest day value valid for any month.
'
' Default value is January 1st.
'
' Examples:
'   ' Set financial year.
'   StartDate = DateFinancialStart(10, 1)
'   ' StartDate -> 2000-10-01
'
'   ' Get financial year.
'   StartDate = DateFinancialStart
'   ' StartDate -> 2000-10-01
'   EndDate = DateFinancialEnd
'   ' EndDate -> 2000-09-30
'
' 2021-05-08. Gustav Brock. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DateFinancialStart( _
    Optional ByVal StartMonth As Integer, _
    Optional ByVal StartDay As Integer) _
    As Date
    
    ' Validate input.
    If IsMonth(StartMonth) And IsDayAllMonths(StartDay) Then
        FinancialStart = DateSerial(Year(DefaultStart), StartMonth, StartDay)
    End If
    If FinancialStart = #12:00:00 AM# Then
        FinancialStart = DefaultStart
    End If
    
    DateFinancialStart = FinancialStart

End Function
```

Note: Partial code only.

Comment: thanks, i am just trying to absorb this and see how it will accomplish my task. I also thought of perhaps adding two more fields on the table, and use `DAO` to update the fields with the `start` and `end dates` as users add records to the DB?

Comment: Just for filtering, you wouldn't add additional fields.